# How to retrieve users given user_level in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Here is two models: user and user_level. User has_many user_levels and user-level belongs to user.

```
class user < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_level
end

class UserLevel < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
end
```

UserLevel.find_by_role('sales') will retrieve all record (w/ user_id) of role sales. How to retrieve user email given user_level with role 'sales'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
User.joins(:user_levels).where(:user_levels => { :role => "sales"}).select("email")
```

or

```
UserLevel.joins(:user).where(:role => "sales").select("email")
```

**update**

```
UserLevel.find_by_role("sales").users
```

Comment: The first one User.joins(:user_levels) works. The 2nd one does not.  Is there other way to retrieve the same info by association between user and user_level? It may be simpler with association. Thanks.

Comment: BTW how to retrieve email and name with the first of above? It seems that the select can either select one column or all columns.

Answer (score 0):

You may have the associations backwards and actually want:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_level
end
class UserLevel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

Then:
@users = UserLevel.find_by_role('sales').users
You can then iterate over the @user collection and use the email within the iterations.

Comment: Assuming the association in the question is correct, how to retrieve the users email? Every user has at least one user_level and one user_level belongs to the user. The association in the answer seems a little odd to me. Thanks.